# PHP - Remove part of string?

Tags: php, string, explode

I have string with following structure:

```
AAA-BBB-CCC or 
BBB-CCC or
CCC-DDD
```

I want to remove first part from these strings.

**Result**

```
BBB-CCC
CCC
DDD
```

Can I do this without "explode" ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What exactly is the rule here? Do you have a reason not to use `explode()`?

Comment: use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: You can use Regular Expression Matching to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a string from the beginning of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517067/remove-a-string-from-the-beginning-of-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```php
$str = "AAA-BBB-CCC";
$str2 = explode("-", $str);
array_shift($str2);
$str = implode("-", $str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if you have always 4 character to delete

```
$string= substr( $your_string, 4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, just use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like this:

```
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, '-'));
```

this cuts at the first `-` - if the parts are always the same length, it's even easier:

```
$string = substr($string, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is not having defined length, you could use regex.

```
$str = "AAA-BBB-CCC";
preg_match('/^.+?-(.+)/', $str, $results);
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: or preg_replace('/^.+?-(.+)/', '$1', $str);

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "
AAA-BBB-CCC
BBB-CCC
CCC-DDD
";

$str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{3}\-)/m', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

This works. Just modify the regex slightly to fit your format if it goes beyond your example string.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part is always four letters, you can use this:

```
$newString = substr($str, 4);
```