# PHP. How to remove filename parts?

Tags: php, regex

I have:

```
$filename =  basename(__FILE__);
$id = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $filename);
```

`$id` is filename without extension now. How can I remove not only extension but prefix and suffix from the file too?

prefix_ineedthis_suffix.php -> ineedthis

---

Update: Thanks for your answers! Unfortunately, I can mark only one answer as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$prefix = 'prefix_';
$suffix = '_suffix';

$pattern = sprintf('/%s(.+)%s/i', $prefix, $suffix);

if (preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches)) {
    $id = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`basename(string $path , string $suffix)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) instead. This can remove the directory part and also the extension part if you want.

```
$id = basename(__FILE__, "_suffix.php")
$prefix = "prefix_";
if (substr($id, 0, strlen($prefix) ) == $prefix) {
    $id = substr($id, strlen($prefix), strlen($id) );
}
```

And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517067/php-remove-a-string-from-the-beginning-of-a-string) this is faster than using RegEx.

Comment: $filename =  basename(__FILE__);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Alvin Wong! Unfortunately, I can mark only one answer as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If "prefix" and "suffix" are parts separated by `_` (underscore), then you might not need regex at all:

```
 $parts = explode("_", $filename);
 array_shift($parts);
 array_pop($parts);
 $ineedthis = implode("_", $parts);
```

OR, if `ineedthis` does not contain underscores for sure then:

```
 $parts = explode("_", $filename);
 $ineedthis = $parts[1];
```

---

If you still wanna use regex then:

```
if(preg_match("/^[^_]+_(.*)_[^_]+\.[a-z]{3,4}$/", $filename, $match))
   $ineedthis = $match[1];
else
   /// oops!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I can mark only one answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode() twice to remove first the extension, then the prefix & suffix.  This will store all the parts within arrays, which is handy if you later need those parts.

Comment: I should have edited my response, I missed the basename() call which would have eliminated both the path and file extension, if called to strip that.  Good catch.