# Remove a word at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

```
$str = "hello world, what's up";
```

How can I check `$str` to see if there is a word "hello" and remove it only if it is at the beginning of the string (first 5 letters)?

Comment: you're missing a `;` ;-) do it "right".

Comment: Just **"A"** possible dupe? Gawd, there literally must be thousands!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `substr`, which is [faster than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517067/php-remove-a-string-from-the-beginning-of-a-string) `preg_replace`:

```
$str = "hello world, what's up?";
$pre = "hello ";

if(substr($str, 0, strlen($pre)) === $pre)
    $str = substr($str, strlen($pre));

echo $str;    // world, what's up?
```

Comment: if you're so concerned with speed, as opposed to code readability, why do `strlen($pre)` twice? save it in a variable. or in this case, why not just make it 5 literally?

Comment: I took the example pretty much straight out of the duplicate I linked to. Good suggestions though!

Comment: +1 for **not** using regex

Answer (score 4):

`^` indicates the beginning of the string, and an `i` flag for a case-insensitive match as per @Havenard's comment.

```
preg_replace('/^hello/i', '', $str);
```

Comment: Also with `/i` flag to a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace('/^hello\b/U', '', $str);`

This will replace 'hello' in 'hello world' but not in 'helloworld'. Because it's replacing just one instance at the start of the string, the amount of cpu use is negligible.

Comment: Why are you putting a `/U`? You don't use quantifiers! However `\b` is a good idea. And i you are hot, you can remove the space after.

Comment: you're right, the 'U' for ungreedy is unnecessary in this case, it's out of habit.